# Can we use PrintWriter Class for saving a string in a file in an Android App? If yes, then how?

Tags: java, android

If we can use PrintWriter Class in making an Android App, then what is the mistake in the following code? My app stops working on pressing the button 'save'

```
public void save(View view)
    {
        text=data.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter writer=null;

        try {
            writer=new PrintWriter(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            msg.setText("FileNotFoundException");
            }
        writer.print(text);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        msg.setText("Data Saved Successfully");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Instead of creating the file yourself, let Android do it.

```
    text=data.getText().toString();
    PrintWriter writer=null;

    try {
        FileOutputStream os = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        writer=new PrintWriter(os);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log exception
        }
    writer.print(text);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    msg.setText("Data Saved Successfully");
```

For more information on basic IO operations, please have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage